# how to display only entered data from multiple textbox control

Tags: c#

I have four textbox controls on my Windows form and now I want to show the data of those textboxes who have some data only

```
if txtbox1="A", txtbox2="B", txtbox3="", txtbox4=""
```

In this case I want to get data (A&B separately) entered by a user for further processing

and

```
if txtbox1="A", txtbox2="", txtbox3="", txtbox4=""
```

In this case again I want to get data (A separately) entered by a user for further processing

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to avoid repetition of "if" and to paste separator between strings correctly is to use Aggregate and IsNullOrEmpty:

```
var edits = new[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };
string text = edits.Select(q => q.Text).Where(q => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(q)).Aggregate((a, b) => a + "&" + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will get the values from text boxes if it is not empty and construct the output string with "&" separating the non-empty values:

```
string output = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox1.text)? "" : txtbox1.text + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox2.text)? "" : "&" + txtbox2.text + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox3.text)? "" : "&" + txtbox3.text + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox4.text)? "" : "&" + txtbox4.text;
```

you can then remove the first "&" if `textbox1` was empty

```
output = String.Join("&",output.Split(new[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statements for the text boxes, and then append it into a single string?

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxX.Text) 
 fullString += " & "+ textBoxX.Text //append string
```

Comment: it will always have " & " at the beginning of the output.